# Proxying requests from domain to another domain cloudflare/aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, aws-certificate-manager

I've two separate projects, one of them is hosted on Cloudflare, and the other one on AWS

Let's say:

`a-stack.com` is deployed on Cloudflare

`b-stack.com` is deployed on AWS (Route53, ALB, EKS, ....) with a subdomain `allocated-for-a.b-stack.com`

Now I am asked to deploy a new subdomain to `a` as for instance `temp-b.a-stack.com` which is gonna route all requests behind the scenes to `allocated-for-a.b-stack.com`

I've tried to add `CNAME` record to Cloudflare as following

```
temp-b.a-stack.com.       allocated-for-a.b-stack.com.
```

Yet I am getting this error

> Your connection is not private
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from temp-b.a-stack.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

When I click on proceed to nonsecure

> This temp-b.a-stack.com page can’t be found. No webpage was found for the web address: https://temp-b.a-stack.com/
> HTTP ERROR 404

And I don't want to delete the current certificate as I cannot modify it in AWS Secret Manager.

I think I am missing the correct approach for doing it, any idea is appreciated